# flask container unusual behavior

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I am running a sample flask app backed with mysql using docker-compose. Here's my compose file.

```
version: "2"
services:
  webapp:
    build:
      context: ./flask/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8000:5000"
    env_file: 
      - ./.env
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - my-bridge1
    volumes:
      - "./flask/flask-data:/usr/src"

  mysqldb:
    build:
      context: ./mysql/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    networks:
      - my-bridge1
    volumes:
      - "./mysql/db-data:/var/lib/mysql"


networks:
  my-bridge1:
    driver: bridge
```

The issue is that when I mount my application directory outside of the container, there is an

```
**error**: __init__.py file is not found
```

Which is found in the WORKDIR.  This issue only occurs when I mount my code volume outside the container, if I mount any other directory then the app works fine.

Here's my docker file for the app:

```
FROM python:3

RUN mkdir /usr/src/FlaskApp
RUN mkdir /usr/src/FlaskApp/code

WORKDIR /usr/src/FlaskApp/code


COPY ./code ./
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

COPY FlaskApp.wsgi /usr/src/FlaskApp/

EXPOSE 5000

VOLUME /usr/src

CMD [ "python", "__init__.py" ]
```

I have tested the mysql container, it copies the files from within the container. But the python container does not.

EDIT1:
When I changes the CMD arg to "ls", the dir is empty. When I changed the CMD arg to "pwd", the output is: "/usr/src/FlaskApp/code"

EDIT2:
What's more strange is that the directories inside the bind volume are created outside. But they are empty!

Comment: can you just `$ touch __init__.py` once or in the script itself?

Comment: @JacobIRR, when i add 'RUN ls' in y dockerfile, the files are present. The image created has the required files. Its when i mount volume from compose, that the files are not found.

Comment: Are you doing `docker-compose build`?

Comment: @hjpotter92 im running docker-compose -f <file-name> -d up --build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data is copied into the python container as well but you are obscuring these data with the bind mount.

First you copy the files into `/usr/src/FlaskApp/code` in your Dockerfile but then you create bind mount at the same location which means that `/usr/src/` will now hold only the contents of the `./flask/flask-data` that are on your localhost (source of the bind mount).

In result, you will end up with `/usr/src/<contents of ./flask/flask-data>`, so if `./flask/flask-data` on your localhost doesn't contain the `__init__.py` file (and the whole directory substructure required by your application), neither will the container.

So all these lines in your Dockerfile are basically irrelevant as long as you are using that bind mount

```
RUN mkdir /usr/src/FlaskApp
RUN mkdir /usr/src/FlaskApp/code
WORKDIR /usr/src/FlaskApp/code
COPY ./code ./
COPY FlaskApp.wsgi /usr/src/FlaskApp/
```

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve and how your application is resolving the paths but a quick fix would be to create another folder under `/usr/src` (maybe `/usr/src/FlaskData`) and mount the local directory there.

```
volumes:
      - "./flask/flask-data:/usr/src/FlaskData"
```

Now you will have both `FlaskApp` and `FlaskData` in your `/usr/src`, but your will need to update file paths in your application accordingly.

[from Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#mount-into-a-non-empty-directory-on-the-container)

> **Mount into a non-empty directory on the container**
>
> If you bind-mount into a non-empty directory on the container, the
> directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount. This can
> be beneficial, such as when you want to test a new version of your
> application without building a new image. However, it can also be
> surprising and this behavior differs from that of docker volumes.

And to answer why the bind mount behaves differently for MySQL container - it doesn't.

You are mounting empty folder to a location where the data is written by MySQL only after the container starts, therefore there is nothing to be obscured there because the destination is empty to start with (the same applies to the python container, if you would write something to `/usr/src` after the container starts, you would see those data appear on the localhost in `./flask/flask`).

Comment: if what you say is true, then why does the mount work for mysql?

Comment: It doesn't. It just seems that it does because you forgot to specify the destination for mysql bind mount. It should be `source:destination`, you are missing the `:destination`. And because of that, mysql container data is not obscured (the volume is not mounted).

Comment: Even with source:dest specified, the mysql container moves data to empty specified folder from within the container.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you mean by that but you can verify the statement by comparing the output of `ls ./flask/flask-data` (before you start the container) with the output of `docker exec <python container> ls /usr/src`.

Comment: I have updated my compose file. I have also tested with mounting /usr/src/FlaskApp folder. but same outcome

Comment: Matus, If the same binding method is working for mysql container, shouldnt it also be working for flask?

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't be mounting to anything on the path if you don't want to obscure those files. That is `/`, `/usr`, `/usr/src`, `/usr/src/FlaskApp`. Mount it let's say to `/usr/src/FlaskData` as I have suggested in the answer an it should work.

Comment: It works the same all the time. It takes the contents of the source and place it to the destination.

Comment: And as for why it works with mysql. That is because the data is generated only after the container starts which is not the case with your python container where data is copied into the container before it starts. With mysql, you are mounting the empty directory and it is empty when the mysql container starts but then it is populated with the data generated by mysql during runtime therefore you can see the data there.

Comment: Matus, your explaination seemed plausible enough. But, please check EDIT2 in my question. If the data is moved from host to container then why are there only empty directories being created in the mounted directory in the host?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Nothing is created outside by the bind mount itself. You are taking the source folder from your localhost, turning it into a "volume" and mounting it to a container (similar to mounting a physical hard disk to a folder in your computer). Nothing is created, it is just a storage where your container can write data and if it is initially empty, container will see it as empty when it starts. If the volume is non-empty, container will see the initial contents (again, same logic as with HDD or USB Flash Drives)

Comment: I understand. And that is what is to be expected. But, I'm telling you. if you want I can email you my whole project

Comment: If you upload the project to github and I can have a look at it. If you choose to do so, please provide exact description of expected vs observed behavior as README.md so that I can quickly test it out.

Comment: here's the repo https://github.com/shasan101/mydocker/tree/mtbc. just try removing the lines 15-16 from compose and check the result and then check the outcome without removing those lines.

Comment: I see what you mean. That is `WORKDIR`' s doing (try commenting it out if you want to check that). It will ensure that the working directory exists so it will still create the folder even if the container's CMD fails. The path is as expected - `/usr/src/FlaskApp` where `/usr/src` is replaced by the bind mount so `./flask/flask-data/FlaskApp`. I run your code and I see nothing weird. Inspecting your code, I see no reason to even use bind mount for flask container and even if, the path is wrong as I have already explained. Also, that MySQL Dockerfile is redundant - you can move it to compose.

Comment: Thanks Matus. This whole discussion really helped me understand what goes on not just with the volume bind but also with the WORKDIR cmd as well. Please add this last comment to the actual answer so that I can mark that. Thanks again.